# Reading a string variable in shell bash line by line and get a number of each line

Tags: bash, shell

I wanna do what the title says. In addition it would be desirable to skip the first line. I have this code

```
#!/bin/bash

output="This\nis 3\na 7\n2 string"
if echo "$output" | grep -q "no"; then   #Just looking for substring "no"
    echo "No running jobs were found";
else
   #read < $output                     #Skip first line
   while read line                   #read the output line by line
   do
      jobID = grep -o '[0-9]*' line     #Take the number (JobID) of each line
      echo $jobID                   #Use the ID to stop the job
   done <<< "$output"
fi
```

But doesn't wotk. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: are those "\n" literal \ followed by n, or are those metacharacters representing actual linefeeds?

Comment: The second. I could just press enter there.

Comment: As `\n` is never getting processed. You can change it to `$'This\nis 3\na 7\n2 string'` to simulate newlines. Additionally the jobID line should probably be something like `jobID="$(grep -o '[0-9]*' <<< "$line")"` Not sure what else you're trying to do, but consider giving [SpellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) a try for syntax issues.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your input string called "output" by adding a number in the first field (line), to demonstrate that that field gets discarded:

```
#!/bin/bash 
output="Th4is\nis 3\na 7\n2 string"
IFS='\'
words=(${output//[!0-9\\]/})
printf "%s\n" "${words[@]:1}"
```

Forget about the above version, it works on literal  \n ...

```
#!/bin/bash
output="Th4is
is 3\n
a 7
2 string"
tmp=(${output//[!0-9]/ })
printf "%d\n" "${tmp[@]:1}"

3
7
2
```

that should do

Comment: I want to use use each number, not just echo it, so this doesn't suit.

Comment: using that output is trivial ... Use your imagination. See, you start with a more complex string, and manage to run it through a loop - why wouldn't you be able to loop through a list of numbers, already ready-to-use-as-they-are?

Comment: All the numbers are in an array. The `printf` is just to show what was captured.

Comment: Oh I see. But first line will never have an int inside, so I'll start counting from zero. It works! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: i added the number to first line to visually verify that it's really dropped. if you dont care about first line, you don't need :0  - just drop that altogether,  ${words[@]}  is what you want then